# The "comment out selected lines" toolbar button is disabled in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

The "comment out selected lines" toolbar button is disabled in Visual Studio 2010. I have text selected an am in a text editor window, but the toolbar button is grayed out. Could I have flipped a setting somewhere?

Edit: This is for c# code editing.

Comment: This isn't clear.  "comment out selected lines greyed out" - I don't know how to parse this.

Comment: Which text editor? That is, which language? I'm not sure they all support commenting.

Comment: It works fine for me C# and JavaScript editors ... dunno what it would do in a normal "text" mode.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth "comment out selected lines" is greyed out. Its a button on the tool bar.

Comment: @pst I guess I mean when i am writing code. Im not great at describing something like this where I cant display code.

Comment: Are you in debug mode? the shortcut key combination if you are using the default bindings is Ctrl K+ Ctrl C for comment and Ctrl K + Ctrl U for uncomment.

Comment: Have you tried disabling all add-ins to see if that fixes the issue?

Comment: I dont have any add ins installed.

Comment: You should, Visual Assist X has a much better comment-out button (and everything else). ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnt want to do this, but uninstalling it and reinstalling it fixed it. Still have no idea what caused it and I have no intention of trying to replicate it as it took me a while to reinstall my packages.

Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a shortcut for that : <kbd>Ctrl+E</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+U</kbd>

Comment: Attempting this doesnt work. I get an error at the bottom of visual studio. This command is bound to comment selection but that command is currently unavailable.

Comment: It's Ctrl+K Ctrl+C (Hovering over the toolbar button shows the locally-bound key.)

Comment: Try Comment => CTRL K + CTRL C and Uncomment => CTRL K + CTRL U

Comment: Using the keyboard shortcut does not work. The actual command is disabled. Using the shortcut displays an error at the bottom of vs saying so.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a little blue padlock icon on the file's tab, then the code is running in the debugger, or else the file is open read-only.  Either way, you can't comment code, neither with the toolstrip button, nor with the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: That was the first thing I checked. Its not running in debug mode.

Comment: @JohnS Do you see a little padlock?

Comment: There is no padlock. Also, the start new instance button is still the green arrow. So if I wanted, I could start a new debug instance.

Comment: Yes. Ive been coding for hours and when i needed the command i noticed that it was disabled.

Comment: Unfortunately, sometimes the editor just refuses to comment/uncomment for you- I have not tracked down what the actual issue is and I'm not sure if it's addons/extensions or not. But I'm in a situation right now where it won't and I've seen it quite a lot in 2010 and 2013.

Comment: +1 Yes my powershel (ps1 and psm1) files have the blue comment and I the comment button is disabled for me too.  I tried ensuring its not read-only and installing some powershell extensions to no avail.